# Magento 2.4.3 UPS integration now that UPS requires OAuth?

Tags: magento2.4, oauth, ups

Our UPS integration stopped working a couple weeks ago due to UPS disabling support for the old UPS Type connection in Magento 2.4.3. We are trying to get an alternate XML integration working but it requires an Access License Number (access key) and as of today, UPS no longer supports access keys, they require OAuth connection:
https://www.ups.com/upsdeveloperkit

We can't get an access key, and it looks like access keys aren't supported anymore anyway.

How are Magento 2 websites recommended to connect to UPS going forward? We have an App created with OAuth included. We just can't get the app to work in the default M2 configuration, as the default configuration doesn't allow for OAuth Client ID and Client Secret field inputs.

Need quick help here, as our website cannot process orders without UPS shipping rates.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else that runs into this, you'll need to contact UPS API support. They will send you the legacy link (which is no longer posted in their developerkit page) to request an access key - apparently access keys will still be supported for another year. Once you get that link, you'll submit your request, they'll email the access key to the primary contact's email address, then you enter that as your Access License Key, your UPS.com login ID for User ID, and your UPS.com login pw for Password.